# Qtestlib log window

Tags: qt, window, logging, qtestlib

I link my program against the qtestlib and include QTest. But then I get a log-window which prompts all the qDebugs, when the application starts even if I set the configuration to release or debug.
Is it possible to include QTest without opening a log-window on application start? I need some functionality of QTest in my program.

Note that i tried below options in the pro file, but this doesn't helped
1) 
CONFIG += qtestlib
CONFIG -= console

2) tried with -silent option, but still log window is coming.

I dont need this log window in my application as i am capturing the logs in a separate file which i am generating using qInstallMsgHandler.

Answer (score 0):

QTestLib is for tests, not production programs.  You can't get rid of the log window without modifying Qt itself.